# Copy and subdivide object without original also being subdivided

Tags: python, blender

I wrote a .py script where I attempt to make two copies of a selected object, one with 1 subdivision and another with 2 subidivions. I ran this script on a plane and it resulted in three planes total, however they all ended up with 3 subdivisions. I think it's because they are all selected during the subdivision call but I don't know how to set the active object.

```py
import bpy

# Get the selected objects
selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects

# Loop over the selected objects
for obj in selected_objects:
    print(obj.name)
    # Check if the object is a mesh
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        for n in [1,2]:
            # Duplicate the object
            duplicate_obj = obj.copy()
            duplicate_obj.data = obj.data.copy()

            # Add the duplicated and subdivided object to the scene
            bpy.context.collection.objects.link(duplicate_obj)
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = duplicate_obj
            # Subdivide the mesh
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=n)
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
            
            # Parent duplicated object to original object
            duplicate_obj.parent = obj
            duplicate_obj.name = obj.name + "_subd_" + str(n)
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that you need to deselect evertyhing and select only the object you want.

```py
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
duplicate_obj.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = duplicate_obj
```